# Image gets shrinked when put inside Stack widget Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

**My expected ui is to have the image occupy full width and have an text on top of it. So I an stack widget but it shrinks down and does not take complete width.**

```
        body: ListView(

        children: [
          Stack(
   
            children: [
              Container(
                child: Image(
                     height:120.0,
                     
                  image: AssetImage('images/business.jpg'),
                ),
              ),
              Text("Business",style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30.0),)
            ],
          )
        ])
```

[image: output]

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I think there is no need for the `ListView` widget as far I know from looking at your code. Remove it and to achieve what you're looking for, add the below properties to the `Image` widget

```
fit: BoxFit.cover,
height: double.infinity,
width: double.infinity
```

so the final version should look like:

```
Image(
     fit: BoxFit.cover,
     height: double.infinity,
     width: double.infinity

     image: AssetImage('images/business.jpg'),
     ),
```